# How to correctly use Netbeans 19 "restful web services from entity classes"?

Tags: rest, netbeans, persistence

To get clarity on the feature, I used Netbeans 19 on OpenJDK 17 and created a new `Java with Maven/Web Application`.
In there I created one entity class, named `WorkItem`. Apart from the fields that the WorkItem got per default I added one more status field including getter and setter.

After building the project I can see the war file in the target folder, and it contains a persistence.xml file that lists my entity class. So far so good, I think it was created/generated correctly.

Now I want to add Restful Web Services for this entity class (Create, Read, Update, Delete) and choose the "Restful Web Services from Entity class". To my surprise the wizard does not show any entity. Why so?

Here is the code for my work item - so far the only relevant code in the project:

```
package com.amadeus.srg.restservice.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author hiran.chaudhuri
 */
@Entity
public class WorkItem implements Serializable {
  public static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(WorkItem.class);

  public enum Status {
    Investigate, Planned, WIP, Validate, Done, Deferred, CarriedOver;
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  
  private Status status;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof WorkItem)) {
      return false;
    }
    WorkItem other = (WorkItem) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "com.amadeus.srg.restservice.model.WorkItem[ id=" + id + " ]";
  }

}
```

Here is the persistence.xml that got generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
  <!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
  <persistence-unit name="my_persistence_unit">
    <class>com.amadeus.srg.restservice.model.WorkItem</class>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is the wizard that does not allow me to choose my entity:
[image]

[image]